# Why does the following code crash when I input a 12 digit number?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have been following a course about algorithms on Coursera and I tried to put what I learned into code. This is supposed to be a "divide & conquer" algorithm and I hope that part is alright. I have a problem I encountered just messing around with it: everything works fine until I input a 12 digit number into the program. When I do that, it just ends the cin and outputs all the previous numbers sorted (blank space if no numbers are before). If you could, please tell me what's wrong if you spot the mistake. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// setup global variable for the number of inversions needed
int inversions = 0;

// function to merge 2 sublists into 1 sorted list
vector<int> Merge_and_Count(vector<int>& split_lo, vector<int>& split_hi) {
    // setup output variable -> merged, sorted list of the 2 input sublists
    vector<int> out;
    int l = 0;
    int m = 0;

    // loop through all the elements of the 2 sublists
    for (size_t k = 0; k < split_lo.size() + split_hi.size(); k++) {
        // check if we reached the end of the first sublist
        if (l < split_lo.size()) {
            // check if we reached the end of the second sublist
            if (m < split_hi.size()) {
                // check which element is smaller and sort accordingly
                if (split_lo[l] < split_hi[m]) {
                    out.push_back(split_lo[l]);
                    l++;
                }
                else if (split_hi[m] < split_lo[l]) {
                    out.push_back(split_hi[m]);
                    m++;
                    inversions++;
                }
            }
            else {
                out.push_back(split_lo[l]);
                l++;
                inversions++;
            }
        }
        else {
            out.push_back(split_hi[m]);
            m++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}

// function that loops itself to split input into halves until it reaches the base case (1 element array)
vector<int> MergeSort_and_CountInversions(vector<int>& V) {
    // if we reached the base case, terminate the loop and feed the output to the previous loop to be processed
    if (V.size() == 1) return V;
    // if we didn't reach the base case
    else {
        // continue halving the sublists
        size_t const half_size = V.size() / 2;
        vector<int> split_lo(V.begin(), V.begin() + half_size);
        vector<int> split_hi(V.begin() + half_size, V.end());

        // feed them back into the loop
        return Merge_and_Count(MergeSort_and_CountInversions(split_lo), MergeSort_and_CountInversions(split_hi));
    }
}

// main function of the app, runs everything
int main()
{
    // setup main variables
    int input;
    vector<int> V;

    // get input
    cout << "Enter your numbers to be sorted (enter Y when you wish to proceed to the sorting)." << endl;
    cout << "Note: do NOT use duplicates (for example, do not input 1 and 1 again)!" << endl;
    while (cin >> input)
        V.push_back(input);

    cout << "\nThe numbers you chose were: " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        cout << V[i] << " ";

    // get sorted output
    vector<int> sorted = MergeSort_and_CountInversions(V);
    cout << "\n\nHere are your numbers sorted: " << endl;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sorted.size(); j++)
        cout << sorted[j] << " ";

    // show number of inversions that were needed
    cout << "\n\nThe number of inversions needed were: " << inversions << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 decimal digits is too long to fit into a 32-bit number, which is how `int` is usually represented. Reading that number using `>>` therefore fails and `cin >> input` converts to a false value, which terminates the loop.

See [`operator >>` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for details of handling failure modes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried using the biggest operator I could find, in this case `unsigned long long int` and it brought the maximum digit number up to 20 so I guess that's the best I can do right now. It's a huge number and I don't think I'll ever need that many digits anyways.

Comment: @DalvAlzar - A `long long unsigned` is not guaranteed to be able to support a value greater than `18446744073709551615`.   That means 19 decimal digit is okay, but 20 may not be (not all 20-digit values are guaranteed to be representable).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum number of base-10 digits that can be represented by the type using the [std::numeric_limits::digits10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) constant:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10 << '\n';
```

Chances are the maximum number of significant digits for type `int` is 9, and you try to supply 12 via standard input. The program doesn't crash, the condition of `(cin >> input)` simply evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

12 digits is too much for 32-bit integer, try to use as `unsigned long long int`, check these limits:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/